# how to pass testng.xml parameter value through mvn command line

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium-webdriver

Below `testng.xml` file has three parameters. I don't want parameter `customerCode` to be hardcoded. I want to pass varying/diffent `customerCode` to the following `testng.xml` file, but also I want to have Peter as a default `customerCode` if just in case I don't provide one through `mvn` command line as follows:

```
mvn test -DcustomerCode=customer1 -Ptestng.xml
```

Below is the `testng.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="false">

    <test name="someTest">
        <parameter name="browserType" value="chrome_win"></parameter>
        <parameter name="Url" value="http://regression.mytest.com/?customerCode=" />
        <parameter name="customerCode" value="Peter"/>

        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="navigateToHomePage" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.automation.customermanagement.createTest.myIntegrationTest" >
            <methods>
                <exclude name="deleteCustomer" />
            </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How do I achieve that? Is there a way to do that?

Below is my POM file. Where do I put `customerCode` property inside the profile?

```
<profile>
    <id>AddMgmtTest</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>admgmttestng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution I implemented and it is working fine!

1) Add following property to `POM.xml` file

```
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>customerCode</name>
                            <value>Subaru</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
```

2) Add this line to test method

```
String customerCode= System.getProperty("customerCode");
```

3) Above line pulls `customerCode=customer1` provided in the following mvn command line

mvn test -DcustomerCode=customer1 -Ptestng.xml

If you do not provide `customerCode` in command line it takes the default value of `Subaru` that is provided in the above property in `POM.xml` file

Comment: note the systemProperties syntax is deprecated, [doc](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html)